# android sdk download finished with wrong size

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having a problem downloading opensense `sdk 15`. The error I get is :

```
[2012-08-12 15:38:32 - SDK Manager] Download finished with wrong size. Expected 27230698 bytes, got 6492 bytes.
```

I am `using Eclipse
JDK 6`

I am new to this and unable to fix the issue on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Its because your internet connection keeps getting interrupted during the download. So here's what you gotta do:

1. Stop all the other tasks that require the use of internet.
2. Ensure that you or your server are not disconnecting it while the Android packages are downloaded.
3. Avoid interrupting the download as in pausing or cancelling it.
4. Keep your PC as idle as possible during the download.

Ensure all these things and it should download fine.